# Vim Airline - how to disable tabline filename?

Tags: vim, tabs, filenames, vim-plugins

When I use Airline's Tabline in Vim, I get the filename twice in my Tabline. Once on the left, and again on the right. I would like to use the extra space on the right for other filenames.

Here is a screenshot: I would like to remove the part in the red oval.

[image: extra filename to be removed]

Comment: Ever solve this?

Comment: I wish. Not yet. Still bugs me every day. Have not had the time myself to devote to looking into it with any depth. (I've looked at the source briefly, but it was not obvious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_splits = 0
```

In your `.vimrc` and restart vim. [Wasn't fixed 'til 2016-02-22.](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/commit/e6ab7bdf6d2f906ecf292268785f80da36e49cba)